# How to add a second datasource to a Micronaut project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, micronaut

I have a java Micronaut project and want to add a second datasource. My Code is working fine as long, as I add the second Datasource. The [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/#jdbc) just said, that I have to add a new source under a new name in my configuration. What am I doing wrong and how do I use the second DB.

My application.yaml

```
---
micronaut:
  application:
    name: transfer-service

---
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/t4dserver
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: password
  germany:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:YYYY/t4dserver
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: password
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
```

The error I get, when I add the "germany" datasource:

```
ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources]

Message: Missing bean argument value: jpaConfiguration
Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) --> MetadataSources.hibernateMetadataSources([JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration],StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources]

Message: Missing bean argument value: jpaConfiguration
Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) --> MetadataSources.hibernateMetadataSources([JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration],StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1174)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:236)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2313)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:199)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:187)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:69)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:288)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:274)
        at transfer.service.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources]

Message: Missing bean argument value: jpaConfiguration
Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) --> MetadataSources.hibernateMetadataSources([JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration],StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.build(AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.java:99)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:201)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1494)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2163)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1849)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1829)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:997)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:982)
        at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateSessionFactoryBuilderDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:205)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1494)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2163)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1849)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1829)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:997)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:982)
        at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateSessionFactoryDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:205)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1494)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2163)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1761)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1172)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: have you injected your "germany" data source as doc suggested?
@Inject @Named("germany") DataSource dataSource

Comment: Do you need to provide a jpg definition for the “germany” datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing my comment as an answer for clarity

I think you would need to add your second datasource to the jpa section thus:

```
jpa:
   default:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            hbm2ddl:
               auto: none
   germany:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            hbm2ddl:
               auto: none
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me, but when I know use

 ```@PersistenceContext(name = "germany")
    private final EntityManager entityManager;


    public GerService(@CurrentSession EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }```

my application still uses the default entityManager??

Comment: I think I would add that as a different question, that might be something more to do with JPA, I have never tried to have multiple entity managers.